# How do I walk a directory using python based on OS version?

Tags: python

I am trying to compare a file stored in a list to the same file located on a server that may be W2K3 or W2K8. I am trying to use a single function to this but am stuck at this if statement. I am trying to figure out how to get the proper directory path into `os.walk():`

```
    if osVer == 'serverW2k3':
        continue
    elif osVer == 'serverW2k8':
        for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk():
```

I did have this working before but had repeating lines so I wanted to simplify the code.
Here is the full class:

```
class checkstatus:
    def __init__(self):
        print 'Checking Status...'
        chkbkpstats = csv.reader(file('c://temp//networkerservers.csv'))

        srvrs = []
        for row in chkbkpstats:
            srvrs.append({'Name' : row[0], 'Instance' : row[1]})

        for srvr in srvrs:
            srvrName = (srvr['Name'])
            srvrInst = (srvr['Instance'])
            w2k3Chk = r'\\%s\d$\DA$Utils\log\networker' % srvrName
            w2k8Chk = r'\\%s\c$\ProgramData\SQL\DA$Utils\log\networker' % srvrName

            try:
                c = wmi.WMI(srvr['Name'])

            except:
                print 'Error connecting to %s to check OS version' % srvrName

            else:
                osVer = c.Win32_OperatingSystem()[0].Caption
                if '2003' in osVer:
                    return 'serverW2k3'
                    #self.fileCheck(w2k3Chk, w2k8Chk, srvrInst, srvrName)

                elif '2008' in osVer:
                    return 'serverW2k8'
                    #self.fileCheck(w2k3Chk, w2k8Chk, srvrInst, srvrName)

    def fileCheck(self, w2k3Chk, w2k8Chk, srvrInst, srvrName, osVer):
        found = False
        if osVer == 'serverW2k3':
            continue
        elif osVer == 'serverW2k8':
            for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk():
                for sqlFile in files:
                    if sqlFile == srvrInst + ".log":
                        found = True
                        print 'The Backup For %s on %s Still Running' % (srvrInst, srvrName)
                    elif sqlFile == (srvrInst + ".ok"):
                        found = True
                        print 'The Backup For %s on %s Completed Successfully' % (srvrInst, srvrName)
                    elif sqlFile == (srvrInst + ".err"):
                        found = True
                        print 'The Backup For %s on %s Has Failed' % (srvrInst, srvrName)
                if not found:
                    print 'No file for %s found on %s' % (srvrInst, srvrName)
```

Comment: Perhaps a better place for this would be [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear, and your sample code obviously isn't your real code (you can't call os.walk with no params), but I think I can guess what you're after.

First, change `fileCheck` like this:

```
def fileCheck(self, path, srvrInst, srvrName):
    found = False
    for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk(path):
        ...
```

Now, in `__init__`, do the last part like this:

```
else:
    osVer = c.Win32_OperatingSystem()[0].Caption
    if '2003' in osVer:
        self.fileCheck(w2k3Chk, srvrInst, srvrName)
    else:
        self.fileCheck(w2k8Chk, srvrInst, srvrName)
```

Comment: Thank you for help!! I had 2 `if` statements prior to me switching. so in my os.walk() statements I had `w2k3Chk` and `w2k8Chk` respectively. To check the file I have in question depends on what version of Windows server the machine has, I.E. W2k8 or W2K3. The paths are different as noted in my original posted code.

Comment: With your assistance abarnert I was able to figure out my issue, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is the snipit of my updated, functional code.

```
        else:
            osVer = c.Win32_OperatingSystem()[0].Caption
            if '2003' in osVer:
                self.fileCheck(srvrInst, srvrName, osVer, w2k3Chk, w2k8Chk)

            elif '2008' in osVer:
                self.fileCheck(srvrInst, srvrName, osVer, w2k3Chk, w2k8Chk)

def fileCheck(self, srvrInst, srvrName, osVer, w2k3Chk, w2k8Chk):
    found = False
    if '2003' in osVer:
        path = w2k3Chk
    elif '2008' in osVer:
        path = w2k8Chk
    for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk(path):
```

Comment: The `if`/`elif` in the first half of the snippet is useless, because you're doing the same thing in both branches. If you need both values in `fileCheck`, just call it without the first `if`/`elif`. If you don't, change `fileCheck` to just take `path` instead of the three variables used to determine it, and then you don't need the second `if`/`elif`.